# Testing material-ui TextField by role using react-testing-library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have some components which include some `mui TextFields`, and there are two situations for my components:

1. One `TextField` is designed for LicenseCode and it can't have a label.
2. Also there are some `TextFields` that will be created via the `map` function also I can't use the label for each of them.

So, I can't use `getByRole` for testing them.
To mitigate this in `testing` I've tried some solutions, But I think there should be a better way. These are my founded solutions:

1. I've `disabled eslint` and use `documentQuerySecletor` for that.

```js
  /*eslint-disable */
  const activationCodeInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.codeItem input');
  expect(activationCodeInputs).toHaveLength(5);

  const systemIdTextarea = document.getElementById('systemId');
  expect(systemIdTextarea).not.toBeNull();
  /*eslint-enable */
```

2. Also, Find an article that used `data-testid` and passed it to `TextField` via`inputProps`

```js
// code
<TextField
 inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'activationCode' }}
/>

 <TextField
  inputProps={{ 'data-testid': 'systemId' }}
 />

// tests
const activationCodeInputs = screen.getAllByTestId('activationCode');
expect(activationCodeInputs).toHaveLength(5);

const systemIdTextarea = screen.getByTestId('systemId');
expect(systemIdTextarea).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Since it is just a `text field` which is a regular element, Do I have to write tests with `getByRole` only as the doc says the first [preferred way](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority), is it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JohannesKlauß , You are right, I've updated it

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a label associated to the TextField and there are multiple TextFields rendered in a list, using and querying via a testid is just fine.

If you have trouble finding the best selector you can always use `screen.logTestingPlaygroundURL()` after you rendered your component in a test. This will give you a URL to the testing library playground where you can check the best selectors for your rendered elements.

Answer (score 2):

For Material UI and React Testing I've just used a label on the Textfield and used getByLabelText for testing to get the input with that label

```js
 <TextField
   label="input label"
   variant="outlined"
 />


screen.getByLabelText(/^input label/i)
```

Comment: In my case the first restriction is not to use label.

Comment: is there multiple textFields on the component you are testing?

Comment: Yes, I put some example in the question